# Determine valid options for the next character in a sequence

Tags: regex, predict, levenshtein-distance

Say I have the regex

```
const string regex = "[A-Za-z0-9]* [0-9]{1,3} [A-Za-z]* ?[A-Za-z]*";

const string address = "ABC 123 Sesame Street"; // this is a valid match
```

and so far I have typed "ABC 123 Se".

As a human, I can see that the next character needs to be a letter. **Is there an algorithm that can do that for a computer?**

I have looked at [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithms, but in order for those to provide information I need two strings, and I only have a string and a regex. [Spell Checking algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) don't quite match my situation either.

I would prefer a generic solution, so that if for some reason I need to allow `123 N 4567 W Paris, Idaho` all I have to do is modify the regex.

**Edit**

I should have said, "as a human, I can see that the regex won't allow the next character to be a number or special character, so I can exclude those options." Thanks for catching that!

Comment: As a human, can you see that the next character needs to be a letter after `ABC 123 Se` because you know what you are going to type is `s` then `a` then ...?  If so, only a human would know what they are going to type (or mis-type) next.   IE:  `Se` could be the abbreviation `SE` for South East, but the user did not capitalize the letter `e` and maybe the next character could be a `.` or a space or...

Comment: Obligatory mention that the next character doesn't need to be a letter - it *could* be a space, or you could just stop there, and it would still match.

Comment: @MarkStewart Sorry for the confusion. I suppose I should have said "As a human, I can see that the regex requires the next letter to be either a letter or a space" so I could exclude numbers/special characters from my list of options.

Comment: No problem; just wanted to clarify your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52150870/5617177), it is possible, you just have to be clever about the regex's you use. For example, if you are parsing IPs:

```
List<string> validNextOptions = new List<string>();
string currentString = "255.3";
string newCharacter = "2";
string partialIP = "^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){0,3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?$";
Regex partialIpRegex = new Regex(partialIP);

if(partialIpRegex.IsMatch(currentString + newCharacter))
{
    validNextOptions.Add(newCharacter);
}
```

This regex will return a match as long as you are progressing toward a valid IP. If you are unfamiliar with how regex's work, I reccomend you post the particularIP string into something like [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) and play with it a bit.

Comment: Depending on your implementation, it might be more efficient to use a string builder instead of simply concatenating strings.